# Need access to a variable outside an isset function

Tags: php, sql, function

First of all I am new to PHP and I am still learning, this site has helped me tremendously with my studies , so thank you to all contributors

I need to get access to the two variables `$t1selected` and `$t2selected` in a second `isset()`  function.

I literally tried everything I know. Im still learning and working with the Book "PHP THe Complete Reference" The book just mentions when you declare variables as globals you can access them across all functions...well in this case clearly not

**Below is part of my first function:**

The var_dump confirms the global variables are holding the correct values

```
// This code gets executed after form has been submitted
function getPlayers(){
if (isset($_POST['select'])) 
{
    global $t1select;
    global $t2select;
 // get 1st team selected
 foreach($_REQUEST["team1_select"] as $t1select) 
 {
    $t1select = $t1select;
 } //end foreach

 // get second team selected
 foreach($_REQUEST["team2_select"] as $t2select) 
 {
  $t2select = $t2select;
 } //end foreach

var_dump($t1select);
var_dump($t2select);

//SOME MORE CODE
```

Now in my second function when I try to reference the two variables  `$t1selected` and `$t2selected`
and do a var_dump on them I get a value null for both variables

**Below is part of my second function**

```
// THIS PART IS TO GET THE STARTING PLAYERS
function PlayerAttributes(){
if (isset($_POST['teamselect'])) {
global $t1select;
global $t2select;
var_dump($t1select);
var_dump($t2select);
 // Get Selected Team For Team1
 foreach($_REQUEST['team1selected'] as $team1players) {
$team1players;
 } //end foreach1
 foreach($_REQUEST['team2selected'] as $team2players) {
   $team2players;
 } //endfor each2
//SOME MORE CODE
```

**My Question**

How can I get access to the two variables `$t1selected` and `$t2selected` across all functions in my code

Comment: Dont make use of **global** keyword ! Why not just pass those as a parameters to your function ?

Comment: Also `$t1select = $t1select` while `$t1select` is declared global is going to mess up your coding logic.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran doing that I get the error "notice undefined variable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the global keyword just pass the value of the variable to the function.

echo the value inside the function.

pass the value like this

```
PlayerAttributes($t1select,$t2select);





function PlayerAttributes($t1select,$t2select){
        if (isset($_POST['teamselect'])) {

            var_dump($t1select);
            var_dump($t2select);
            // Get Selected Team For Team1
            foreach($_REQUEST['team1selected'] as $team1players) {
               echo $team1players;
            } //end foreach1
            foreach($_REQUEST['team2selected'] as $team2players) {
               echo $team2players;
            }

        }
        }
```

Comment: Then I get the error "Undefined variable: t1select"  "Undefined variable: t2select"

Comment: Did you pass the value

Comment: I passed the variable which contains the value

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice of coding, but as per the scenario which you mentioned another option is:

```
<?php
define('T1_SELECT',$t1select);
define('T2_SELECT',$t2select);
?>
```

it will be available in global scope, you can access it in complete application anywhere by
T1_SELECT
AND
T2_SELECT.

Thanks
Amit